# direct or indirect for the types of training exprience

Tags: machine-learning

I have a question,

in machine learning we define 2 types for the type of training experience:

Direct and indirect.

I searched a lot about the difference but I coud not find. Is anyone familiar with these?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How much is a lot? A quick google search shows me plenty of results.

Comment: I jsut need the answer why max entropy is useful wich I could not find. Because max entropy shows the more impurity which is not good

Answer (score 3):

In his book ["Machine Learning" (1st ed.)](http://a.co/7tOtv6e), Tom Mitchell explains this as follows (see section 1.2.1, page 5):

> For example, in learning to play [checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts), the system might learn from *direct* training examples consisting of individual checkers board states and the correct move for each. Alternatively, it might have available only *indirect* information consisting of the move sequences and final outcomes of various games played. In this later case, information about the correctness of specific moves early in the game must be inferred indirectly from the fact that the game was eventually won or lost.

He further states:

> Here [using indirect feedback] the learner faces an additional problem of *credit assignment*, or determining the degree to which each move in the sequence deserves credit or blame for the final outcome. Credit assignment can be a particularly difficult problem because the game can be lost even when early moves are optimal, if these are followed later by poor moves. Hence, learning from direct training feedback is typically easier than learning from indirect feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example Playing Chess
Direct experience : Learning the Rules of playing chess. Learning the different moves of different coins. Example : elephant moves only straight, soldier moves only one step at a time etc.

Indirect experience :
Learning from the previous experience, if particular movement of the coin in the game has led the to win, this movement will be assigned some reward or credit, if particular movement has led to loose game, penalty is assigned.                          This experience of the previous game is used to make coin movement against particular step, so that game can be won.